# Illegal variable name error when using grep -v '^$'

Tags: grep, csh

I get an error *Illegal variable name* when I use this line of code:

```
set users = "` last | sort | tr -s '\t' ' ' | grep '[0,2][0-4]:[0-5][0-9] -' | grep -v '^$' | grep -v '[2][0-1]:[0-5][0-9] -' `"
```

But it works fine when I use this code:

```
set users = "` last | sort | tr -s '\t' ' ' | grep '[0,2][0-4]:[0-5][0-9] -'  | grep -v '[2][0-1]:[0-5][0-9] -' `"
```

The code should store people who logged in between 22:00 and 05:00 (excluding 05:00) into a variable named users. It should also remove any empty lines which are in the output. This is what I'm trying to do in the first code, but it gives me the aforementioned error.

Comment: I'm not sure of your core problem, but if you're using `grep -v '^$'` to say "Skip blank lines", it's probably easier and clearer to use `grep .`.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to give the exact error message that you're getting.

Comment: The exact error message is "Illegal variable name." and what would the "grep ." do?

Comment: Please paste the entire line of text that appears.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/387babdfc5917d21b1b4b6ba4159c73f the first line is me executing the file with arguments

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to explain it, but it is one of these typical CSH pitfalls.

A <dollar> (`$`) between <double-quotes> (`"`) (independently if they are in between <back-ticks> (`` ` ``) and <single-quotes> (`'`) are **always** concidered to be variable names. So if the word following the <dollar> is not a valid variable name, the thing starts to complain. Example:

```
$ grep "foo$" file.txt
Illegal variable name.
```

This is exactly what your problem is. You wrote something similar too

```
$ set var = "`grep -v '^$' file.txt`"
```

and even though the <dollar> is between <single-quotes> which are in-between <back-ticks> for command substitution which is again between <double-quotes> to retain the blanks and tabs of the command substitution, it just does not matter! There is no hope! You used <double-quotes> with all good intentions, but it just blew up in your face! Resistance is futile, your <dollar> will be assimilated to resemble a variable, even when it does not! CSH just does not care! You just want to cry! You cannot even escape it!

If you make use of `last` from *util-linux*, you might be interested in the flags `--since` and `--until` (see [here](https://www.mankier.com/1/last) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241718/display-users-that-logged-in-since-a-date-using-last)). Otherwise you might use the following command line:

```
set users="`last | awk '/(2[2-3]|0[0-4]):.. [-s]/'`"
```

This will match all lines where the user logged in between 22 en 05 (excl) and is potentially still logged in.

As a general note, I would suggest switching from CSH to BASH for many reasons. Some of them are mentioned [here](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) and [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Comment: Well thats a shame then. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @MichaelKročka I have added a possible alternative for your command line.